# How to parse nested XML file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<Types>
   <Type id='1' name='sport'>
      <SubTypes id='1' name='football' />      
      <SubTypes id='2' name='tennis' />
   </Type>   

   <Type id='2' name='education'>
      <SubTypes id='1' name='school' />      
      <SubTypes id='2' name='university' />
   </Type>
</Types>
```

I have the previous XML file, and I want to parse it using Javascript, how can I access to all SubTypes for a specific Type ?

I used

```
var x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Type");
```

to parse the Types , but how can I parse the Subtypes for each type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Type"); 
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var subTypes = new Array();
  var y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("SubTypes")
  for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++){
    subTypes.push(y[j])
    // or you could just process them here
  }

  // process the subtypes in this type

}
```

That should get you there... idk what you want to do with these subtypes though

Answer (score 0):

You could also use xpath:

```
var x = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var subtypes = x.evaluate( '//Types/Type/SubType', x.documentElement);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript